# Does change in OS time causes change in clock chip time?

Tags: systemtime

Say if a person is changing the his OS time, will that be having any impact on the clock chip time?

Comment: What exactly do you mean "clock chip"? Depending on WHAT you mean it can be yes or no

Comment: sorry that's how I learned it. what i actually meant is http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/c/clock.htm

Comment: Following the link you posted, if you mean number 1. then NO. If you mean number 2 then YES. Number 3 is the OS clock you are talking about. Those 3 things are all different things even though they share the name "clock"

Answer (score 0):

No, the clock on the a chip does not have anything to do with the time set in your operating system. A chip has a clock which returns a signal every x ns to provide a timer for the system. But your system-time depends on the rate of the chips - clock, meaning if you change the frequency of the chips clock the system timer will run faster/slower.

Comment: so is there a way to find the actual current date, even if the user changes the OS date, using this clock chip time?

Comment: nope, like i mentioned you cannot depend on the clock of the chip as it only provide a signal for the internal system, but you could get the time from a ntp server

Comment: @ArunSudhakaran: using the mentioned timer interrupt? No.

Comment: @Kris There IS actually a clock chip. It's even called a clock. It's the real-time-clock and it is indeed a chip usually communicating with the CPU via SPI or I2C, is powered by a small watch battery, is never turned off. You will know the battery for the clock chip have died when your PC's time reverts to 1970 every time you reboot

Comment: @slebetman isn't there just a timer and a bit memory that will kept alive from the battery? anyway its still not possible to get the actual time of from that 'clock' if it wasn't set somehow. usually one sets it manual or gets the time from the server